# how to understand angular ng-class and dynamic class

Tags: angular, ng-class

I try to use ng-class, I need to create dynamic class in angular. But can't find some easy and clear for me tutorial or something like that.

For example I have something like that:
app.template.html

```
<div class="items-container" >
    <ul>
        <li class="item" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
            <div class="icon" ng-mouseenter="mouseEnter(tag.name)">
                <img src="/assets/{{tag.icon}}" />
            </div>
            <div ngClass="{'show' : false, 'hide' : true, 'tag-name'}">
                {{tag.name}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

app.ts

```
export class AGmainMenu {

    tags = mainMenuItems[0].tags;
    itemShow: false;

    mouseEnter(tag){
        console.log("mouse enter : ", this, tag);
    }
}
```

And I want that after mouseenter on div.icon, sibling div (.tag-name) change class from hide to show. And I really  don't know how to connect changing class with function mouseEnter.

Comment: You're using AngularJS directives (ng-mouseenter) within an Angular template. This can't possibly work. Here are examples of usage of NgClass: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass. And here are more explanations: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngClass. I found all this by simply searching for NgClass in angular.io, the official documentation of Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the base, it works like:

- You create some class (css/scss)
- You bind that class dynamicly to your html element based on some condition.

**Example**

```js
isBlack = true;
```

```css
div.my-dynamic-class {
  background-color: #000000;
  }
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'my-dynamic-class': isBlack}"></div>
```

where isBlack would be the boolean based on that class will be applied.

Here is the complete documentation: [LINK](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exaclly what I need. What I missed.

Comment: @Eva any time ;)